# Sorting string date array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I was having some problem when trying to sort the string date array in JavaScript.

```
function drawLineChart(crisislist){
    crisislist.sort(function(a,b) {
        a = a.split('-').reverse().join('');
        b = b.split('-').reverse().join('');
        return a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
    });
    for(var i = 0; i < crisislist.length; i++){
        console.log(crisislist[i].date);
    }
}
```

Basically my crisislist got other stuffs other than date:

```
 crisislist.push({category: marker[2], month: marker[13], date: marker[14]});
```

When I tried to sort it, it gave me an error message:

```
a.split is not a function
```

I wonder is there any way to sort it directly in the crisislist rather than create another string date array which only has the date field?

Thanks in advance!

The console.log without the chunk of sorting code gave me these dates:

[image]

Comment: please add some data, or at least the date string.

Comment: Add `console.log(a)` before `a.split(...` to see what is `a` there.

Comment: @SangbokLee the a is Object {category: "1", month: "02", date: "01-02-2017"} because my crisislist is an object array but it is not sorted

Comment: Yes, and `Object` has no `split()` method. `string` does.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `a.date.split(…)`. You don't have an array of date strings, but an array of objects containing the strings.